# How do I create an endpoint on AWS for the bot application for .NET?

Tags: c#, botframework

I registered a bot on the MS Bot Framework but how will I set an endpoint....will that be in Azure or could I use AWS?

Comment: Use whatever makes you happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not actually need to set an endpoint to use your emulator.  So if you are just testing in the emulator do not worry about the endpoint yet.  Webchat will give you errors but if you are testing on the emulator it will work fine.  You will also not need to use the app id and password to test in the emulator.

You will need an end point when you want to move to another channel.  For that, you can literally use whatever cloud hosting service you want.  You just need to host it somewhere AWS or Azure will both work, so use what you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are creating an endpoint. That can be anywhere you like (including on your local machine - although that would make a for a poor deployment choice). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart